# How to use getAttribute() method for laravel eloquant for database table filed like d_1, d_2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a table schema with column names like `d_1`, `d_2`,.. I want to modify that fields value before use in blade file.

I have tried laravel model method like below, but unfortunately it not worked.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelName extends Model
{
   public function getD1Attribute()
   {
      return (float) number_format($this->attributes['d_1'], 2);
   }
}
```

can any one help me with this specific case ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about it "not worked"? how are you trying to access this accessor?

Answer (score 0):

You might be having issues with this due to the name of the field 'd_1'. The mutator is looking for camelCase which probably makes it 'd1' because the numbers don't have a capital it wouldn't know that the 1 is not part of the word. You can test this by using the helpers something like this:

```
$name = 'D1';
$snakeCase = Str::snake($name); // i expect this would be 'd1'

$name = 'DOne';
$snakeCase = Str::snake($name); // i expect this would be 'd_one'
```

I hope this helps.